# Windows Batch Files, for %%F in (*.png) do sam2p.exe %%F %%~nF.eps include subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do i make this one take all .png files in subfolders also, now it only takes those in the current folder.

for /r %%F in (*.png) do sam2p.exe "%%F" "%%~nF.eps"  does save the files in teh folder its run in.

F:\Documents\Dropbox\05011 - Road Signs v2\Documentation\Bitmaps>sam2p.exe "F:\D
ocuments\Dropbox\05011 - Road Signs v2\Documentation\Bitmaps\HOG\4\out.png" "out
.eps"

I need it to save it in the folder its taken from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for /r %%F in (*.png) do sam2p.exe "%%F" "%%~pF%%~nF.eps"